# Ignoring time-zone changes after saving NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimezone

My apps are time-zone agnostic: I want the dates and times saved and displayed in a manner that ignores changes in the user's time zone.  Once I've recorded the local date/time of some user action in my app (typically by saving timeIntervalSince1970 in an sqlite DB), I want to show the same date/time string regardless if the user's time zone has changed or not, and regardless of the user's various time zone settings in his device.

For example, if a user's action occurs at 1:15 pm local time in San Francisco, and then he opens my app a few days later in New York, I want that prior action to still appear as 1:15 pm (not 4:15 pm), and even if he's manually set some other time zone in his device (e.g., Chicago).  A second action in New York at 9:00 pm there, should forevermore display as 9:00 pm, even when back in California.

I could achieve my goal by saving every date/time as a string (based on the user's local time zone), and then never use the date methods again -- but then I couldn't do date/time arithmetic (e.g., sorting).

How can I be time-zone agnostic when saving and retrieving dates/times?

(Apple's Calendar app seems to behave this way when Time Zone Override is on, but only if I manually set the event time.)

Comment: You can "cheat" and arrange for your NSDate values to always be relative to the local time zone (ie, always set the formatter to UTC, regardless of the local time zone).  There be dragons, however.

Comment: You mean do this at launch: [NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Chicago"]]; -- yes, there are dragons.  If I do that and use the app in some other time zone, the time is saved as if I was in Chicago.  If my action is at 2:00 pm in Florida (on my iPad which is showing Florida times) and I save the result of [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970], the app displays the action as happening at "1:00 pm."

Comment: No, I mean always set the date formatter to UTC before use.  Then whatever time you enter will be redisplayed as exactly the same time when you NSLog the NSDate, with no timezone offset.  But (among other things) you need to do a swizzle when you capture the current time with `[NSDate date]`.

Comment: @Hot Licks -- please be more specific about your "swizzle."  I don't see how you plan to remove TZ dependence -- the trick is in capturing the date correctly.  That's my problem.

Comment: When converting a character date to NSDate use UTC.  Then, when taking the current time with `[NSDate date]` you need to convert that to local time somehow -- simplest is to use a dateFormatter set to local TZ to convert to char, then a dateFormatter set to UTC to convert back to NSDate.  (But understand this is non-standard.)

Comment: @Hot Licks. I'm trying desperately to understand your comment about UTC, but it eludes me.  I'm initially creating a date using [NSDate date], and thereafter I always want to display it as the clock time at the capture location, regardless of the iPad's current TZ.  If you're suggesting I store the date as a string, then I realize I need to initially format it using the local time zone.  So, why would I need to convert to UTC?  Saving the string would work (but seems like a kludge), or saving the timeIntervalSince1970 AND the then local TZ (probably the best way).

Comment: I'm simply saying that the easiest way to get an NSDate object containing "now" internally recorded in local time vs UTC is to convert the `[NSDate date]` value to char form using a date formatter set to your timezone, then *immediately* convert back to NSDate using a date formatter set to UTC.  There are more elegant ways, but even more confusing.  (As I said, using NSDate objects that reflect local time has some pitfalls.)

Comment: @Hot Licks -- I grok your idea now: (1) convert any `[NSDate date]` to a string using a formatter set to the `systemTimeZone` (that string will match the local clock time), (2) convert that string back to a date value using a formatter set to GMT, (3) save that value in the database (there's no need to save the TZ in the database as the local TZ will be ignored from now on). (4) Later, when a date value is fetched from the DB, convert it to a string using a date formatter set to GMT (but don't show any TZ in the string). -- If you create an answer saying that (copy/paste okay), I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working solution (@Hot Licks deserves the credit, but he didn't post an answer):

1. Subclass NSDate and add a `gmtDate` method that does the conversion from local TZ to GMT.  `gmtDate` uses `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"` as the format string, which also drops seconds from the value.  Like this:

```
+(NSDate *)gmtDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"; // drops the seconds

    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]; // the local TZ
    NSString *localTimeStamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    // localTimeStamp is the current clock time in the current TZ

    // adjust date so it'll be the same clock time in GMT
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    NSDate *gmtDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:localTimeStamp];
    return gmtDate;
}
```

2. In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` add `[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]]` so all date formatters make date strings in GMT by default (but never include the timezone in the format string).
3. When the date/time of a user action needs to be saved, get the date via `[NSDate gmtDate]` and save that value in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Record the time zone along with the timestamp.  Use that time zone when formatting the timestamp later.  You'll need to add another column to your database table.

Comment: Yes, I believe that would work.  It just seems there ought to be a way to do this purely via the time zone methods (e,g,. setting a default time zone).  Maybe not.  I'm surprised that I haven't seen this issue discussed elsewhere.

Comment: @Jeff - Most people want to avoid what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Hot Licks -- Avoiding TZ changes after entry should be common.  Take any calendar app.  A week before traveling from the USA to Australia, I enter some appointments in advance.  E.g., I enter a 12:00 noon lunch on day next week.  When I get to Australia (and set my iPad to Aussie time), me and anyone else would want that appointment to show noon, not six hours and a day different from that.  In my app, I record events as they happen, in the then-local time zone.  Later, when my user looks at those events (in a different time zone), they'd not want them converted to some whacko time.

Answer (score 0):

Either save the time zone, as Rob suggested, or save the time as both an `NSDate` **and** a string. Use the string for the UI and the `NSDate` for calculations.

Or hey, do all three, if you need them.